# Keras custom loss function - how to access actual truth values and predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working with time series forecasting with Keras LSTM. I take the last n_input_steps occurrences of the series and try to predict one step forward. For example, if my time series is [1, 2, 3, 4] and n_input_steps = 2, the supervised learning dataset would be:

[1,2]--> 3

[2,3]--> 4

Thus, the series to be forecast (y_true) would be [3,4].

Now I have a Keras model to predict such type of series:

```
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(neurons, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in, 1)))
        model.add(RepeatVector(1))
        model.add(LSTM(neurons, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss,run_eagerly=True)
        hist=model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, verbose=2,validation_data=(testX,testY))
```

And my loss function is:

```
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    print(kbe.shape(y_true))
    y_true_c = kbe.cast(y_true,'float32')
    y_pred_c = kbe.cast(y_pred,'float32')
    ytn = y_true_c.numpy()
    print(ytn.shape)
    # Do some complex calculation requiring the elements of y_true_c and y_pred_c. 
    # ...
    return result
```

In my poor understanding, if I call `model.fit(trainX, trainY,...)` with trainX corresponding to [[1, 2], [2, 3]] (an array in the proper shape) and trainY corresponding to [3, 4], the y_true inside my_loss should be a tensor corresponding to [3, 4]. However this is not that I am finding. The print output of my loss function (the shapes of tensor and array) is:

```
tf.Tensor([32  1  1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
(32, 1, 1)
```

regardless of the size of the input array. And if I print the values of the array, they have no remembrance to the original values. Even if I remove all the layers of the model, keeping a bare Sequential, I get the same shapes. Therefore, I am completely lost.

Comment: You cannot use a numpy array in your loss function. You must use tensorflow/keras operations. That is necessary for automatic differentiation (for backpropagation).

Comment: By default, Keras uses a batch size equals to 32 (unless you set another), perhaps that is what you are missing here. So you are not printing out the shape of one sample, but a batch of a bigger size (32 in this case).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Indeed, the main problem was the batch size, but on top of that, the data comes in shuffled, that is why it becomes even more confusing. So, for my purposes, I will try to use batch_size=len(trainX) and shuffle=False in model.fit(). I will check if my model works and I may post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, I did further search and found the response there is a default batch size ruling, as pointed out by Jorge Avila. The length of 32 is the default
used by Keras. The truth data and the predicted data come in batches of this size, so I should use `batch_size=len(trainX)` in the call to `model.fit()`. Furthermore, on top of that, the data comes in shuffled, that is why it becomes even more confusing. So, I have to use `shuffle=False` also in `model.fit()`.

However, as pointed out by Jakub, even with these modifications, my intended loss function will not work because Keras requires symbolic derivatives of the function, which cannot be achieved by having logic which requires the numpy values. So, I have to start from scratch with another loss function acceptable by Keras.

Answer (score 0):

Keep batch_sizes in multiples of 32-1024 depeding on you're data as 2** of always works as it is a common, but you shouldn't have to use shuffle in fit as TimeseriesGenrator is where the changes need to be made not fit.